# Why is $]-\infty,0]$ a closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis

Maybe i'm confused, but why is $]-\infty,0]$ a closed interval? I mean, we know that $-\infty$ is a limit point of $]-\infty,0]$, but isn't contained in the interval.

Comment: Infinity is not a limit point of that set, as $\infty$ is not a real number. A set is closed if the limit of every convergent sequence is contained in the respective set. A sequence which diverges to $\infty$ is not convergent (hence why we say "diverges to $\infty$").

Comment: it's a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why is there suddenly an uptick of this reverse-bracket notation for open intervals?  So like, the open interval $(0,1)$ being represented as ]$0,1$[.  It's horrible.

Comment: It is an interval, and it is a closed set.  I had one instructor who always said "closed bounded interval" when he wanted $[a,b]$.  We asked him why he did not just say "closed interval"; he explained this was the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$-\infty$ is **not** a limit point of $(-\infty, 0]$, because **it is not a point**. In the context of real numbers, $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not numbers, they are simply symbols used to shorten some notations. For example, the set $$A = \{x\in\mathbb R| x < a\}$$ can be written more compactly as $A=(-\infty, a]$. In writing this, $-\infty$ is just a symbol used to write down an expression. Saying that the symbol $\infty$ is a "point" makes, in this case, just as much sense as saying that the symbol "$($" is a point. It is not. Out of all the symbols in the expression $(-\infty, 0]$, only one of them represents an actual number.

---

The set $(-\infty, 0]$ is a closed interval for a simple reason: because it is:

1. An interval.
2. A closed set.